# jQuery dialog not displaying div on change

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, dialog

I am using dialog to display a form and echo back message on submission. That works well. I also have a dropdown menu that on selection of value from that populates 2nd dropdown. This works well on it's own, but if I try to merge the two, then the div id="divId" is not being displayed or populated from the change. Now i will be the first to admit that my jQuery knowledge is basic to say the least, so I would appreciate any help from the experts. I have included code for your attention and await your comments. Thanks

This code is in seperate function.js

```
// Function to add box

function addbox() {

    $("#boxaddform").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        resizable: true,
        modal: true,
        title: 'Submit a box intake request',
        width: 470,
        beforeclose: function (event, ui) {
            $("#addbox").html("");

        }

    });

    $('#boxsubmit').click(function () {

        var box = $('.box').val();
        var service = $('#service').val();
        var authorised = $('.authorised').val();
        var data = 'box=' + box + '&authorised=' + authorised + '&service=' + service;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "boxesadd.php",
            data: data,
            success: function (data) {
                $("#boxform").get(0).reset();
                $('#addbox').html(data);
                //$("#form").dialog('close');
                $("#flex1").flexReload();

            }
        });
        return false;

    });

    $("#boxaddform").dialog('open');

}
```

html

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
      $(function() {
            $("#company").change(function() {
              if ($(this).val()!="") $.get("getOptions.php?customer=" + $(this).val(), function(data) {
                $("#divId").html(data);
                });
              });
      });
</script>

<!--- Form to add box -->

<div id="boxaddform" style="display:none;">
  <form id="boxform" method="post" class="webform" name="boxform" />

        <label for="company">Select a Company:</label>
                <select name="company" id="company" />
                    <option SELECTED VALUE="">Select a Company</option>
                        <?php
                                do {  
                                ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $row_Recordsetcust['customer']?>"><?php echo $row_Recordsetcust['customer']?></option>
                        <?php

                    } 
                                while ($row_Recordsetcust = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordsetcust));
                                $rows = mysql_num_rows($Recordsetcust);
                if($rows > 0)

                    {
                                mysql_data_seek($Recordsetcust, 0);
                                $row_Recordsetcust = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordsetcust);
                    }

                ?>
            </select><br />
            <div id="divId"></div><br />
        <label for="service">Enter service level:</label>
                <select name="service" id="service">
                    <option SELECTED VALUE="">Select an option</option>
                    <option value="Standard">Standard</option>
                    <option value="Rapid">Rapid</option>
                </select>
                <br />
        <label for="box">Enter a Box#:</label>
                <input id="box" name="box" type="text" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all inputbox box" />

        <label for="authorised">Requested By:</label>
                <input name="authorised" type="text" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all inputbox authorised" id="authorised" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['kt_name_usr']; ?>" /><br />
    <div id="addbox"></div>
      <button id="boxsubmit" class="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

getOptions.php

```
<?php
    $customer = mysql_real_escape_string( $_GET["customer"] ); // not used here, it's the customer choosen

    $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
    $db = "sample";
      if (!$con)
        {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
        }

        mysql_select_db($db, $con);
        $query_rs_select_address2 = sprintf("SELECT * FROM company_com where idcode_com = '$customer'");
        $rs_select_address2 = mysql_query($query_rs_select_address2, $con) or die(mysql_error());
        $row_rs_select_address2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs_select_address2);
        $totalRows_rs_select_address2 = mysql_num_rows($rs_select_address2);



          echo 'Select delivery address'.'<select name="customeraddress">';
          echo '<option value="">Select delivery address</option>';
          while ($row_rs_select_address2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs_select_address2))
          {
          $address=$row_rs_select_address2['address1_com']. " ".
          $row_rs_select_address2['address2_com']. " ".
          $row_rs_select_address2['address3_com']. " ".
          $row_rs_select_address2['town_com']. " ".
          $row_rs_select_address2['postcode_com'];
          echo '<option
          value="address">'.$address.'</option>';
          }
          echo '</select>';
?>
```

Comment: that's quite a long script ....

Comment: @mihai how can I compress it? it has everything I need. I've seen bigger :-)

Comment: Can you just post the rendered HTML? I don't think we need to see how it's all created...

Comment: @onekidney I cannot post the rendered html because the dialog output does not render (at least not in my browser ) output but will show in firebug. Correct me if I am wrong, but isn't it beneficial to see the code no matter how big, for example, in my code there could be an error that could easily be spotted? thanks

Comment: :) You're wrong, unfortunately, as we don't want to read your whole program. There's a sister site for requesting [code reviews](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/). This site is just to answer specific questions, which very rarely require that much code to be answered.

Comment: @eykanal Why should I want I want code review? I Need an answer to a question, and that question has to do with my code. Even with other posts on this forum, people have requested the code.

Comment: "Correct me if I am wrong, but isn't it beneficial to see the code no matter how big, for example, in my code there could be an error that could easily be spotted?" Yes, that's why you should only post the minimal amount of relevant code. Posting huge blocks almost always means you didn't spend enough time figuring out the *minimal* amount of *relevant* code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try putting this

```
$("#company").live('change', function() {
  if ($(this).val()!="") $.get("getOptions.php?customer=" + $(this).val(), function(data)  {
    $("#divId").html(data);
  });
});
```

in the first part of the scripts that you provided.

My idea is that maybe the change handling code is not capturing the dropdown and is not runned at all.
In order to test that put alert('test'); inside your current $("#company").change(function(){...}); block.

Comment: That did it. What is the difference between live and change. I had read that trigger is used in preference to change?. thanks

Comment: oopps, spoke to soon. It is throwing error in IE8. Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=' in C:\wamp\www\sample\admin\getOptions.php on line 18

Comment: line #18 starts around this area: echo 'Select delivery address'.'<select name="customeraddress">';

Comment: You can search for "jquery live" in google and read about it. Basically with 'live' you attach events to all DOM elements including the one that did not exsist when the page was created. That includes all dynamically added/created elements like your dropdown.

Comment: This is a PHP error, right? Most likely you have it in every browser.